Crash issue from Microsoft official Win32 C++ custom WinRT XAML control tutorial
Got a crash after following the official Microsoft official Win32 custom WinRT XAML control tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/xaml-islands/host-custom-control-with-xaml-islands-cpp:
    ucrtbased.dll!issue_debug_notification(const wchar_t * const message) Line 28   C++
    ucrtbased.dll!__acrt_report_runtime_error(const wchar_t * message) Line 154 C++
    ucrtbased.dll!abort() Line 61   C++
    ucrtbased.dll!terminate() Line 59   C++
>   MyDesktopWin32App.exe!__scrt_unhandled_exception_filter(_EXCEPTION_POINTERS * const pointers) Line 93   C++
    KernelBase.dll!UnhandledExceptionFilter()   Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart$filt$0()   Unknown
    ntdll.dll!__C_specific_handler()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException()  Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RtlDispatchException()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RtlRaiseException()   Unknown
    KernelBase.dll!RaiseException() Unknown
    vcruntime140d.dll!_CxxThrowException(void * pExceptionObject, const _s__ThrowInfo * pThrowInfo) Line 82 C++
    MyDesktopWin32App.exe!winrt::throw_hresult(const winrt::hresult result) Line 5017   C++
    MyDesktopWin32App.exe!winrt::check_hresult(const winrt::hresult result) Line 5087   C++
    MyDesktopWin32App.exe!winrt::Windows::Foundation::IActivationFactory::ActivateInstance<winrt::MyUWPApp::MyUserControl>() Line 6582  C++
    MyDesktopWin32App.exe!winrt::MyUWPApp::MyUserControl::{ctor}::__l1::<lambda_143_>::operator()(const winrt::Windows::Foundation::IActivationFactory & f) Line 62 C++
    MyDesktopWin32App.exe!`winrt::MyUWPApp::MyUserControl::MyUserControl'::`1'::<lambda_143_>::<lambda_invoker_cdecl>(const winrt::Windows::Foundation::IActivationFactory & f) Line 62 C++
    MyDesktopWin32App.exe!winrt::impl::factory_cache_entry<winrt::MyUWPApp::MyUserControl,winrt::Windows::Foundation::IActivationFactory>::call<winrt::MyUWPApp::MyUserControl (__cdecl*)(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IActivationFactory const &)>(winrt::MyUWPApp::MyUserControl(*)(const winrt::Windows::Foundation::IActivationFactory &) && callback) Line 6419 C++
    MyDesktopWin32App.exe!winrt::impl::call_factory_cast<winrt::MyUWPApp::MyUserControl (__cdecl*)(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IActivationFactory const &),winrt::MyUWPApp::MyUserControl,winrt::Windows::Foundation::IActivationFactory,`winrt::MyUWPApp::MyUserControl::MyUserControl'::`1'::<lambda_143_>>(winrt::MyUWPApp::MyUserControl::{ctor}::__l1::<lambda_143_> && callback) Line 6458    C++
    MyDesktopWin32App.exe!winrt::MyUWPApp::MyUserControl::MyUserControl() Line 62   C++
    MyDesktopWin32App.exe!InitInstance(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, int nCmdShow) Line 126  C++
    MyDesktopWin32App.exe!wWinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance, wchar_t * lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) Line 44 C++
    MyDesktopWin32App.exe!invoke_main() Line 123    C++
    MyDesktopWin32App.exe!__scrt_common_main_seh() Line 288 C++
    MyDesktopWin32App.exe!__scrt_common_main() Line 331 C++
    MyDesktopWin32App.exe!wWinMainCRTStartup(void * __formal) Line 17   C++
    kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()  Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()  Unknown


Here's the project that I have setup, based on the tutorial above. https://drive.google.com/file/d/15o7Gp2xAEr0OXtMLzvbpqU0txFFZyvQj/view?usp=sharing
Any clue why that would happen?
Using Visual Studio 2022 v17.11.4
What have been tried:
Tried to understand the crash stacktrace and have no clue at the moment. I also double checked the steps and made sure I didn't miss any step from the tutorial for about 3 times.
Expected result:
A window with the correct UI will be displayed when running the project solution.
Actual result:
Crash when running the project solution. No window was displayed.

Load debug symbols to get a more meaningful stack trace.

Those are the compiled files from NuGet packages. How do we get the debug symbols for those?

I was referring to system modules (like ntdll.dll). In Visual Studio, you can right-click a stack frame that currently displays "Unknown" and select the "Load Symbols..." command from the context menu. See Debugging with Symbols for general help on setting up your debugging environment.

Cool, thanks for the guides. I have updated stacktrace after using the "Load Symbols".

This isn't actually a crash. It's more like an emergency shutdown following a failed type lookup. You're probably missing the appropriate <activatableClass> entries in the application manifest (or a manifest altogether). See Create an application manifest in the linked tutorial.

I'm using Option 1 instead. Do you mean I should try option 2 so I can see a more detailed stacktrace?

If you are going with MSIX deployment (Option 1), I assume that you have to launch your program via the Start Menu shortcut (which the installer presumably added). You can try using a manifest instead. This might resolve the issue altogether (rather than merely producing better diagnostics). This whole class registration and discovery business is still opaque to me. A question I asked a while back might be related.

Your comment is spot on! Using Option 2 works! However, I still need Option 1 because I need to package it so I can upload to Microsoft Store.
I have tried Option 1 with other simpler Win32 project (without the UWP project), I can run the solution without problem.

I also tried to create app package using the Publish option, it says "Manifest references file 'placeholder.exe' which is not part of the payload.", which confuses me abit. Plus, there's a small triangle warning icon at the project reference under Dependencies in the Windows Application Packaging Project. It doesn't show anything when hovering on top of it.

@IInspectable, do you happen to know how to solve the Option 1 issue? Or getting the right stacktrace? I have tried to use the Extension solution from the link you shared, but it complains "Application configuration is incorrect". Not sure if I have setup wrongly or it just doesn't for this project.
